# two variants building at same time

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I know this topic doesn't seem very clear, but i really didn't know how to name it!

when i open my android studio project, suddenly the build page show two modules that is building, then second one fails with silly errors and first one continues on `syncing...` forever

[image]

i tried to clean, rebuild, invalidate cache and restart...
but none of these helped.

WHAT is this? why it happens? my project was Ok some days ago!

the error Log:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: constraint-layout
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: design
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: appcompat-v7
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: cardview-v7
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: crashlytics
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: constraint-layout-solver
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-v4
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-fragment
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: animated-vector-drawable
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-core-ui
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-core-utils
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-vector-drawable
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: transition
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: loader
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: viewpager
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: coordinatorlayout
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: drawerlayout
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: slidingpanelayout
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: customview
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: swiperefreshlayout
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: asynclayoutinflater
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-compat
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: versionedparcelable
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: collections
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: cursoradapter
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: exifinterface
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: runtime
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: documentfile
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: localbroadcastmanager
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: print
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: viewmodel
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: interpolator
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-annotations
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: beta
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: crashlytics-core
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: answers
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: fabric
Affected Modules: app


WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
Affected Modules: app
```

Module Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sadrcom.bazisara"

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1089
        versionName "0.8.9"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.4.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.github.Andy671:Dachshund-Tab-Layout:v0.3.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
}
```

Comment: post the error, not the screen, and the build.gradle of the module

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti added to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was resolved by deleting Gradle cache folder on:

```
C:\Users\userName\.gradle\caches
```